# Empty button error - WAVE tool

Tags: php, wave

First of all I would like to ask you If errors in WAVE tool are important?

I get 4 errors and don't know how to fix them. Maybe I start with empty button, the code is:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" class="search-form searchform clearfix" method="get">
   <div class="search-wrap">
      <input type="text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Szukaj', 'colormag' ); ?>" class="s field" name="s">
      <button class="search-icon" type="submit"></button>
   </div>
</form><!-- .searchform -->
```

And the error states:

> What It Means: Empty button - A button is empty or has no value text.
>
> Why It Matters: When navigating to a button, descriptive text must be
>   presented to screen reader users to indicate the function of the
>   button.
>
> How to Fix It: Place text content within the  element or give
>   the `<input>` element a value attribute.
>
> The Algorithm... In English: A  element is present that
>   contains no text content (or alternative text), or an `<input
>   type="submit">`, `<input type="button">`, or `<input type="reset">` has an
>   empty or missing value attribute

What should I do to fix this message?

Comment: Sorry, Im not from english speaking country as you... Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it but you might try `<button class="search-icon" type="submit">SOME USEFUL TEXT HERE</button>`

Comment: Yeak it works but looks very stupid now ;-)